# Show Only First Cell in Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I employ a table view and table view cell on top of a map view on a view controller, and I only want to display the first cell. I have tried setting numberOfRowsInSection to 1, and that crashes my app.

The data filling the cell and determining the number of rows in sections comes from Core Data. I have successfully shown only the data that I want, it's just repeated a bunch rather than showing just one cell.

I want this, like I have in my separate Table View Controller:

[image]

Instead, I get this:

[image]

My cellForRowAt:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Configure cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MapTableViewCell") as! MapTableViewCell
    cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.horizontalStackView.addBackground(color: UIColor.white)

    // Get data
    var cellLocation: Location

    for location in locations {
        if location.latitude == annotation.coordinate.latitude && location.longitude == annotation.coordinate.longitude {
            cellLocation = location

    YelpClient.sharedInstance().loadImage(cellLocation.imageUrl, completionHandler: { (image) in

        performUIUpdatesOnMain {

            cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image
            cell.nameLabel.text = cellLocation.name
            cell.priceLabel.text = cellLocation.price
            cell.displayRating(location: cellLocation)
        }

        YelpClient.sharedInstance().getOpeningHoursFromID(id: cellLocation.id, completionHandlerForOpeningHours: { (isOpenNow, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("There was an error: \(String(describing: error))")
            }

            if let isOpenNow = isOpenNow {

                performUIUpdatesOnMain {

                    if isOpenNow {
                        cell.openLabel.text = "Open"
                        cell.openLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
                    } else {
                        cell.openLabel.text = "Closed"
                        cell.openLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 195/255, green: 89/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1.0)
                        cell.openLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: .semibold)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    })
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

numberOfRowsInSection:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return locations.count
}
```

Let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: What was the reason for crash when you set number of rows to 1 ? What was the content of error log ?

Comment: "I employ a table view and table view cell on top of a map view on a view controller, and I only want to display the first cell." Then why not consider using a UIView instead of a tableview?

Comment: @CodeFarmer You make a good point. I struggled when using just a horizontal stackView to display all this data originally. Likely I need to embed it in a UIView, which I did not do. I had already successfully implemented the tableView approach in another controller so it made it faster to approach it that way, though they may not be the best long term design solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class variable that receives just the data you want even if it is just one item:

```
var location1Item = [location]()
locations1Item.append(locations[0]) //Or the item you want to show
```

Now use the `location1Item` to populate the `tableView`

numberOfRowsInSection:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return location1Item.count
}
```

cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Configure cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MapTableViewCell") as! MapTableViewCell
    cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.horizontalStackView.addBackground(color: UIColor.white)

    // Get data
    var cellLocation: Location

    for location in location1Item {
        if location.latitude == annotation.coordinate.latitude && location.longitude == annotation.coordinate.longitude {
            cellLocation = location

    YelpClient.sharedInstance().loadImage(cellLocation.imageUrl, completionHandler: { (image) in

        performUIUpdatesOnMain {

            cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image
            cell.nameLabel.text = cellLocation.name
            cell.priceLabel.text = cellLocation.price
            cell.displayRating(location: cellLocation)
        }

        YelpClient.sharedInstance().getOpeningHoursFromID(id: cellLocation.id, completionHandlerForOpeningHours: { (isOpenNow, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("There was an error: \(String(describing: error))")
            }

            if let isOpenNow = isOpenNow {

                performUIUpdatesOnMain {

                    if isOpenNow {
                        cell.openLabel.text = "Open"
                        cell.openLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
                    } else {
                        cell.openLabel.text = "Closed"
                        cell.openLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 195/255, green: 89/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1.0)
                        cell.openLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: .semibold)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    })
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This worked and is the correct answer to my specific question. @CodeFarmer makes a good point that a UIView is likely a more succinct solution to my actual design architecture so I do want to call that out too.

Comment: Pleased for helping